# Insanely small font size in Photoshop

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

At 100% zoom the Arial font (and every other font too) becomes readable only at 1200 pt font size, what could be causing this?

This problem seems to exist for previous versions of photoshop but I did not find the cause.

I am ready to share more info, I just don't really know what to add.

- Adobe Photoshop Version (CS5) 12.0 x64
- OS: Windows 7 x64 ultimate

Comment: If you go to create a new image, what does it say for the resolution and the pixels per inch?

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090307144624AAFsdlt

Comment: @BrianZ yeah, there we go, it says 1 pixels per inch (can you post it as an answer?). Sorry to have bothered everyone for such a silly mistake.

Comment: @techie007 Yahoo Answers is less than reputable. :<

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore What's suggested there is a valid thing to check, and the user hasn't stated they have.  Reputable or not (in your opinion), the info there is worth checking into (IMO) by the OP (note I left it as a comment and not an answer).  Turns out it WAS the answer the OP needed, but I'll leave the rep for Brian Z or whomever wants to type up a proper answer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The pixels per inch is probably set too low. One quick way to check what you are working with is to create a new image and see what it suggests as the default. At least 72 pixels per inch is typically what you want.